# MPI_alltoallv with sendcounts as an array of long (not integer values)

Tags: mpi

I need to use `MPI_Alltoallv`, but my sendcounts (2nd argument) is an array of long integers. `MPI_Alltoallv`, however, requires it to be an array of integers. I am not sure if it's a limitation. Is there any way to solve this issue?

Comment: Cast the long integers to integers ?  Or are you really sending such huge amounts of data that you can only express the sendcounts as long integers ?  I don't think that MPI can be persuaded or forced to interpret long integers correctly in this kind of context.

Comment: It's not MPI that prevents casting a vector of long int to a vector of int. This is invalid C. You might get lucky if int and long as equivalent, but they are often not.

Answer (score 2):

Usually, if your data is so large that it doesn't fit in an integer size, it's probably not going to be safe to send it with a normal MPI library. There's some non-standard work out there to make it possible, but if you want to stick to officially supported methods, there are a few ways to handle it safely.

- Use MPI datatypes. These will let you encapsulate the data into datatypes that can be (theoretically) arbitrarily large. They can be a bit complex to use, but if you're only sending large, contiguous memory regions, it's not too difficult.
- Send your data in multiple chunks. If you limit your messages to size `INT_MAX`, then you can avoid the issue altogether. You'll just have to send more messages.
- Use [BigMPI](https://github.com/jeffhammond/BigMPI), a library by Jeff Hammond which encapsulates some of the grossness of sending large amounts of data. I don't think he's calling that code production-ready, but you can take a look at it to see if it's what you need.

Answer (score 2):

I like Wes's answer for its completeness.  If you want a concrete example of how a program might deal with large counts, here's how I did it in ROMIO:

http://git.mpich.org/mpich.git/blob/HEAD:/src/mpi/romio/adio/common/utils.c

It's worth pointing out, too, that if you are sending multiple gigabytes of data, MPI_ALLTOALLV is not going to do anything more efficient than a bunch of MPI_Isends and MPI_Irecv calls.

Comment: Though your last statement is perfectly valid, I would still advise against reimplementing `MPI_Alltoallv` or any other MPI collective. Debugging cryptic messages about the InfiniBand driver not being able to create new queue pairs (e.g. due to too many simultaneously established connections and/or mapped buffers eating up all entries in the HCA's memory translation table) is way worse than trying to overcome the argument type issue.

Comment: One can reimplement alltoallv with send-recv and not drop ALL n messages into the queue at once ;-)

Answer (score 0):

In addition to excellent answers by others, another thing you can do is use MPI_Neighbor_alltoallv, which has MPI_Aint displacements. I use this trick in BigMPI already and you can reuse my comm-to-(dist-graph-comm) utility function easily enough.

Note that it is not guaranteed that long and MPI_Aint are equivalent. This is true with MPICH 3.2 on my machine right now, but it is not something on which you can depend when writing portable code. Please copy your displacement vectors or change them to be MPI_Aint if you use neighborhood v-collectives.